# What is Game Center friend recommendation based on?

Tags: ios, game-center

My iPad game center app shows friend recommendations. That list includes people that I do not know, people I have heard of but have never had direct contact, as well as people whom I regularly communicate with but never via Apple products. It is freaky. What information is friend recommendation based on?

Answer (score 1):

It's friends of your friends and people who have some of the same games installed as you.

Comment: How are friends decided?

Answer (score 0):

From the settings, I think it's giving you recommendations based on you Contacts and Facebook.

As shown in the picture:
[image]

Picture comes from here:
http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/how-use-game-centre-on-ios-3542729/